# Why would a sender consistently ignore MX preference?

Tags: email, dns, smtp

In order to migrate, I adjusted my old MX servers' preference, and added my new one; my goal being that the new one should be used, but if there's some problem, hopefully it's a problem early enough that it bounces and the old MX server is used instead.

This mostly worked. However the old MX server is still (after a couple of days) receiving some mail; consistently from the same single legitimate sender, and a load of spam.

When the old server receives this mail, it simply relays it to the new  one, and it's accepted fine, so I think it's very unlikely it's actually being rejected in the first place.

I adjusted the priorities to `10` (new) and `65535` (old) in case more of a gap would make any difference; it didn't.

If it were just spam, I'd just ignore it as odd or even as a tactic - but why would the legitimate sender do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right about the spam. Here's this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record#Spammers):

> Spammers may deliberately direct mail to one of the backup (high distance) MX servers of a domain first, on the assumption that such a server will have less effective anti-spam filters. An anti-spam technique called nolisting is based on assuming this behaviour.

As far as the legitimate sender doing this, it doesn't seem to be a requirement to select mail servers based on priority. A similar question asked [here](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/21529999/DNS-question-MX-record-priorities-don't-seem-to-be-honored.html) yielded this response:

> I have seen that some DNS servers will return MX records in a rotating order period and some smtp servers will use the 1st MX record returned, with out looking at the priority.

Some people have reported that if the primary mail server was slow to respond or completely unresponsive, then the client MTA end up using the "backup" one. To test that, you could turn off the backup one temporarily.

More resources:

- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/374700-incoming-email-not-using-priority-mx-record
- https://serverfault.com/questions/666460/change-of-mx-records-priority-seems-not-to-entirely-working
- https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/546293-why-is-the-mx-priority-value-being-ignored

Comment: Thanks, I did try removing the backup one, and had to wait until this morning for another email from the legitimate sender that was doing this, and it did indeed come through fine.